# Portal website not working correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, autospinstaller

for developing I created a 3 server architecture in Hyper-V: AD, SQL Server 2014, SharePoint 2013 SP1. The AutoSPInstaller script runs trough perfectly, however I encounter a weird problem: the Central Administration and the Mysite are working and are also accessible from other machines.

But: the initial portal website has errors. If I set it `http://localhost` (port 80) in the script it seems to work but the site isn't accessible from other servers (error 400/404). If I don't set it to `http://localhost/` the website can't be displayed anymore.

What is wrong?

Some more information:

```
Web Application for 'Portal': http://locahost, Port: 80
---Site Collection: http://l ocalhost
Web Application for 'Mysite': http:// l ocalhost, Port: 8080
---Site Collection: http://localhost:8080
```

The Central Administration displays this web applications:

```
SharePoint Central Administration, URL: http://sp2013:28551 (sp2013 = computer name)
Portal, URL: http://sp2013, Port: 80
Mysite, URL: http://sp2013:8080
```

Comment: what happen if you browse http://sp2013 ?

Comment: It shows a 404 error after prompting for my credentials.

Comment: 404 means file not found...could you please share following information....AAM settings for the Portal web application, also from central admin> application management > manage content database and see if any database attach to portal web application? also from application management, view all site collections> check if any site collection exist their for portal....i am guessing no site collection created so far

Answer (score 0):

You can change your host file by binding sp2013@80 to localhost but first I suggest you to try configuring alternate access mapping from central administration.

However are you sure you really nead localhost binding? Why not just navigate from sp2013?

Comment: If I enter http://sp2013 I receive a 404 error after prompting for my credentials. 

Not sure what I can do. Does alternate access mapping in the central administration help to access the portal website from another computer which is in the same domain and logged in as the same administrator?

Comment: If you access from same domain you don't need binding. You could just modify the alternate access mapping.